# Android targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, build.gradle

I've set my targetSdkVersion to 29 in build.gradle and now I'm getting the following lint error:

"Redundant attribute layout_marginLeft; already defining layout_marginStart with targetSdkVersion 29"

on this TextView:

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="@{dto.description}" />
```

My question is, if I do what is recommended and remove layout_marginLeft from the TextView will this cause problems on phones running an sdk less than 29?

Comment: See [Native RTL support in Android 4.2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdk = 16, you should keep `android:layout_marginLeft`, otherwise you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks @shmakova, can you elaborate a bit please. How did you arrive at your answer?    Does the error message mean that all versions between min & target don't need both layout_marginStart& layout_marginLeft defined?

Comment: `android:layout_marginStart` is not working on Android 4.1 (api 16), so if your minSdk higher than 16, you don't need it @Shanie